# How can I exchange two elements in a python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I didn't really find any solution because "swap", "change" and "exchange" are really overloaded words.
I am still in the beginning phase of learning and trying to exchange the words "empty" and instead let it insert the parameter behind "add_city".

```
cities = ["Tokio", "empty", "Berlin", "Accra", "empty"]

def add_city(article):
    for article in cities:
        if article == "empty":
            article = cities[1]
            cities.append(article)
            break
print(cities)



add_city("Paris")
```

So in the end it should print out:

```
["Tokio", "Paris", "Berlin", "Accra", "empty"]
```

Can anyone give a quick guidance?

Comment: what is shelf? and in the output, there is one "empty" element in the list. Do you want to replace the first occurrence?

Comment: You say you're trying to "swap" or "exchange" items, but your (non-working) example shows a simple replacement.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is supposed to simply replace the given element. I simply don't know a way to do that yet and couldn't find any similar question.. Although it is not supposed to replace ANY element, but only the ones saying "empty".

I guess it most probably is a brainfart, but a thinking way too long on this very simple matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use index to do that:

```
cities = ["Tokio", "empty", "Berlin", "Accra", "empty"]

def add_city(city, cities):
    cities[cities.index('empty')] = city
    print(cities)

add_city("Paris", cities)
```

Index will return the index of the first appear of 'empty', and you simply fill that index with the city you pass.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular example, working with indexes might be a good idea. Use the enumerate() iterator:

```
cities = ["Tokio", "empty", "Berlin", "Accra", "empty"]

def add_city(article):
    for idx, elem in enumerate(cities):
        if elem == "empty":
            cities[idx] = article
            #cities.append(article) - not needed
            break #this code will replace the first occurence of "empty"
    return cities

print(add_city("paris"))
```

will print out:

```
['Tokio', 'paris', 'Berlin', 'Accra', 'empty']
```

Comment: I think Rakesh got there first :) enumerate is a really good option while iterating over lists in python

Comment: Actually understood the index way first, which might be caused by my lack of knowledge or deep understanding. But I will try to adopt that way! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I read your posting accurately, you need to replace "empty" with the parameter value.
Find the location of "empty"; stuff the new city name there.

```
def add_city(city, cities):
    if "empty" in cities:
        cities[cities.index("empty")] = city
```

There are more Pythonic ways to do this, but I think this one is at your current level of coding.